# Regression Model Tool

Tags: model, regression

It may sound silly to ask, but I am looking for a tool(or Program) that will give the type of regression model based on the data points.
For example:

X-axis(independent variable): 50,542,632,865,952,1025,1558,2558

Y-axis(dependent variable): 10,50,500,800,5588,5225,6852,12555

If I gave the above data points as input, then it should return which is the closet model that fits it(like power model, or linear model, or logarithmic...)

Or it may also return the equation that meets close to these data points(need not to be linear).

Answer (score 0):

I ran the posted data through the "function finder" on my open source zunzun.com curve fitting web site, looking for equations with three or less parameters. The Standard Vapor Pressure equation, "y = exp(a + (b/x) + c*ln(x))", appears to be a likely candidate with parameters a =  1.2874282196949840E+01, b = -2.4014635886351439E+03, and c = -3.2062368249209683E-01 yielding RMSE = 204.6 and R-squared = 0.9171. The site uses the Differential Evolution genetic algorithm to determine initial parameter estimates for fitting non-linear equations, which is what makes the equation search possible.

[image]